# How to get Cognito ID Token with in browser ?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am building web application (using ReactJS) uses Cognito user pool for user management, which is going to be serverless using cloudfront, api & lambda. I looking for help on how to get Cognito IDToken with in browser using Javascript with actually signing in. I just want the token and pass it to an API which will extract authentication information from token and use it for some specific purpose.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [`AWS Amplify`](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify)

Answer (score 4):

Amazon Cognito tokens are stored in the browser's local storage but it is not recommended to access them directly from there since they might become expired.

It's better to get them using the SDK, from which you can get the session, which in turn refreshes the tokens for you (if they become expired) and provides you with valid tokens if the session is still valid. For example:

```
import * as AmazonCognitoIdentity from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";

const poolData = {UserPoolId: "USER_POOL_ID", ClientId: "CLIENT_ID"};
const userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

// React
const cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
  if (cognitoUser != null) {
    cognitoUser.getSession((err, session) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else if (!session.isValid()) {
        console.log("Invalid session.");
      } else {
        console.log("IdToken: " + session.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log("User not found.");
  }

// React Native
userPool.storage.sync((error, result) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else if (result === "SUCCESS") {
    const cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
    if (cognitoUser != null) {
      cognitoUser.getSession((err, session) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else if (!session.isValid()) {
          console.log("Invalid session.");
        } else {
          console.log("IdToken: " + session.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log("User not found.");
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Storage sync error.");
  }
});
```

Comment: Also note that getCurrentUser() refreshes the tokens automatically using the refresh token.